# pig-0.9.0.pom does not contain all its runtime dependencies, like pig-0.8.1-cdh3u1.pom

Tags: maven, apache-pig

maven noob, be patient... 
I'm upgrading from cdh3u1 to apache hadoop 0.20.203.0 and pig 0.9.0. I used to have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.1-cdh3u1</version>
    </dependency>
```

and running them from inside eclipse, with junit run configuration worked great.
Now I have:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.203.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I got NoClassDefFoundError: jline/ConsoleReaderInputStream on runtime.
I ended with adding all these dependencies manually until it worked:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jline</groupId>
        <artifactId>jline</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.94</version>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr-runtime</artifactId>
        <version> 3.2 </version> <- this is 3.0.1 in cdh3u1, but probably changed in pig 0.9.0
    </dependency>      
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>r06</version>
    </dependency>
```

What gives? why isn't maven automatically pulling my dependencies and putting them in the classpath?

Comment: jline version incompatibility manifests in this error message: `ERROR 2998: Unhandled internal error. jline.ConsoleReader.setDefaultPrompt(Ljava/lang/String;)V

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: jline.ConsoleReader.setDefaultPrompt(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

Comment: antlr version incompatibility manifests in this error message: `ERROR 1200: can't look backwards more than one token in this stream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven has a feature called [Transitive dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies), so you don´t have to specify the libraries that your own dependencies require.

ConsoleReaderInputStream is in the Jline JAR. When you were using Pig.0.8.1-cdh3u1, you didn´t have to add the Jline dependency because it is declared in [Pig.0.8.1-cdh3u1.pom](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/public/org/apache/pig/pig/0.8.1-cdh3u1/pig-0.8.1-cdh3u1.pom). [Pig 0.9.0.pom](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/pig/pig/0.9.0/pig-0.9.0.pom) does not have Jline dependency declared anymore, that´s the reason you had to add it by yourself. As for the reason JLine was removed from Pig, you have to ask the developers of that project.

Comment: checked, and this is exactly as you describe. I've updated the version numbers listed in the answer according to what I found in the pig-0.8.1-cdh3u1.pom